# Why can't I add concrete classes to a list of interfaces which the concrete classes implement?

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, conceptual

I am having trouble adding an instance of a class that implements an interface to a *list of that interface*; I am getting type validation errors.

I have the following:

- A base class `Pet` containing two fields common to all pets: `PetId` and `Name`.
- An interface `PetInterface` enforcing two fields: `PetId` and `Name`.
- Concrete classes `Dog` and `Cat` that inherit from `Pet` and implement `PetInterface`.

Code:

```cs
public interface PetInterface
{
  public int PetId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
  public int PetId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog: Pet, PetInterface
{
}

public class Cat: Pet, PetInterface
{                  
}
```

Scenario 1:

```cs
var dog = new Dog();
var cat = new Cat();

List<PetInterface> petInterfaceList = new List<PetInterface>();

petInterfaceList.Add(dog1); //Error: cannot convert Dog to PetInterface class
petInterfaceList.Add(cat1); //Error: cannot convert Cat to PetInterface class
```

Scenario 2:

```cs
var dog = new Dog();
var cat = new Cat();
var petList = new List<Pet>({dog, cat});

List<PetInterface> petInterfaceList = petList //Error: cannot convert List<Pet> to List<PetInterface>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make class `Pet` implement the interface, then inherit from `Pet` in `Dog` and `Cat`

Comment: What is the C# version of that : `Inherits Pet || Implements PetInterface`?

Comment: Your code seems to contain a lot of typos. Can you fix them first? This includes, but is not limited to: `dog1` and `cat1` should be `dog` and `cat` in the first code snippet, right?

Comment: Do `public class Pet : PetInterface` and `public class Dog : Pet` - the same for Cat. As Pet now implements the interface and Dog/Cat inherit from Pet, they will also implement the interface automatically. A side note: the naming convention for interfaces is that they start with a capital letter I – it should be IPet, not PetInterface.

Comment: "`var cat = new Dog();`" you have a confused dog

Comment: @devNull Lol. That was a good one! :)

Comment: Given what you have (conceptually), Scenario 1 should work just fine (see [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nSFsVH)). The errors in Scenario 2 are simply because there is no conversion between `Pet` and `PetInterface`, as other have pointed out.

Comment: Please paste your actual code, this doesn't compile. And after removing the "public" from the property declarations in PetInterface, scenario 1 works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think your example code will compile.
2. You don't set access level on interface properties, methods, there will be no `public`, `private`, just `int` and `String`
3. You could probably just do away with the Interface altogether and just inherit from base class Pet.

   ```
       //The interface contract -> Assures these properties are part of base class
       public interface PetInterface
       {
           int petId { get; set; }
           String name { get; set; }
       }

       //base class which defines contract properties of interface PetInterface
       public class Pet : PetInterface
       {
           public int petId { get; set; }
           public String name { get; set; }
       }

       public class Dog: Pet
       {
          //Add dog specific properties/methods
       }

       public class Cat: Pet
       {
         //Add cat specific properties/methods
       }
   ```